# Is it possible in Windows 8.1 to use thumbnail view w/o generating thumb.db files?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, windows-8.1, thumbs.db

ie. generate thumbs per folder view on-the-fly for non read only drives?

Regarding internal drives including system.

Comment: What's the use case?

Comment: I am slightly confused about what this question is asking. You want to use a thumbnail view, but don't want the thumbs.db file to ever be created? I don't think that's even possible without [disabling thumbnails completely](https://superuser.com/a/677832/487867).